# Is there a way to show exact time with hour, minute, second and millisecond "" running like digital watch "" in python

Tags: python

I have this code  " i want to show time like digital watch which updates times "  It shoud be in single line and like digital clock which updates times automatically.

```
import time
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

print("Local current time :", localtime)
```

This code return day, month, date, time, and year. But can we show running time.

python version 3.8

I want to show output like seconds and millisecond running like digital clock. In a single line

Comment: Look at the `datetime` module

Comment: Try to be more clear in your question about what exactly it is you are trying to do

Comment: I want to print time like " digital clock "  in a single line. which updates times automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    time = str(datetime.now().time())
    print(time, end='\r')
```

Its a high precision microsecond clock that over wrights its self on one line.

Comment: why does it blink sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean by blink? The underscore? Just click out of the terminal/cmd windows, also you should run it as a .py file separately.

Comment: I've run your program in pycharm and it blinks almost every seconds. it dosen't show like constant. It keeps blinking.

Comment: Run it in the native Python 3.x IDLE app and run it from outside of the program (it should be opened as a terminal windows).

Comment: It works fine in Python 3x IDLE app but, in Pycharm it blinks.

Comment: So the problem is from Pycharm not the script.

Comment: Yes. You can say that

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a loop that keeps displaying the time?

```
while True:
    print(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time())))
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you want to keep printing the time one the same line, you an use

```
print(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time())), "       ", end='\r')
```

(ending with \r instead of a newline moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line you just printed. The whitespace at the end is to make sure all the previous characters were erased.)

Comment: i want to print hour, minutes, second and millisecond in a single line and running like a digital clock.

Comment: and your program shows output in multiple line and your second "print" option isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

No need to use the datetime module

```
import time

time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time())) #time.time() gives UTC time
```

- Output

```
'14:47:10'
```

Comment: First of all OP doesn't use `datetime`, second this doesn't answer the question which is how to print the clock in real-time

Comment: Yes he uses `time` which is the one I used as well, I don't see where it says for the clock to update in real time, but you if you want `just that` you can put that in a `while True` loop

Comment: your code dosen't show any kind output at all.

Comment: and i've mentioned that it should run time like " digital clock "  which means update like real time in a single line.